# DRY code: how to call an implementation from another protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have some code I want to DRY up, I don't want to repeat/maintain the same code at multiple places.

```
protocol Programable {
    var log: String { get }
}

protocol Convertable {
    var status: String { get set }
}

extension Programable where Self: NSManagedObject {
    var log: String {
        return <managed object related stuff>
    }
}

extension Programable where Self: NSManagedObject, Self: Convertable {
    var log: String {
        return <managed object related stuff> + status
    }
}
```

How can I call the first extension's `log` in the second extension, so I don't have to repeat the details in the code?

Comment: I'm curious, can you even do this with a `protocol` in Swift? Your second extension is a different _thing_ from the first. This isn't like class inheritance and so you're defining a new implementation of `log` and constraining that implementation when type conforming to `Programmable` conforms to both `NSManagedObject` and `Convertable`.

Comment: It seems to work as expected, calling the most specific if it applies, and falls back to the more generic otherwise. I wasn't sure if this would work before I implemented it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to call the same overload if only the constraints differ. Instead, move the commonality into something private. There is no naming convention for this.

```swift
extension Programmable where Self: AnyObject {
  var log: String { where_Self_is_AnyObject_log }
  private var where_Self_is_AnyObject_log: String { "where Self: AnyObject" }
}

extension Programmable where Self: AnyObject & Convertible {
  var log: String { "\(where_Self_is_AnyObject_log) & Convertible" }
}
```